# Dynamic choices model

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my first commerce website. I have various products with totally different choices.(models,colors,quality,etc) So I want each of my products to have different choices. I'm confused what kind of Field should I add to my product Model. And how to I manage to add choices to each product. Thank you very much

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description         = models.TextField()
    price               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    category            = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    slug                = models.SlugField(default='hello')
    image               = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True) 
    available           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Model fields are not supposed to be dynamic, they are not designed for that as they are directly related to the database. I would try create Product as abstract model and extend that for each type of item such as shoes, bag, clothes etc. Abstract model gives you the elasticity of creating other models and most importantly, your base abstract class is **not** created as a table in database, so you do not have to bother with the base Product field. Here is a sample `models.py`:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description         = models.TextField()
    price               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    category            = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    slug                = models.SlugField(default='hello')
    image               = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True) 
    available           = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Shoe(Product):
    colors              = models.CharField()
    size                = models.IntegerField()

class Clothes(Product):
    colors              = models.CharField()
    size                = models.CharField()
    clothes_type        = models.CharField()

# etc.
```